# An integer is required? open()

Tags: python, file-io, integer, argv

I have a very simple python script that **should** scan a text file, which contains lines formatted as *id*='*value*' and put them into a dict. the python module is called chval.py and the input file is in.txt. here's the code:

```
import os,sys
from os import *
from sys import *

vals = {}

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

for line in val_f:
    t = line.split('=')
    t[1].strip('\'')
    vals.append(t[0], t[1])

print vals

f.close()
```

when i try to run it i get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "chval.py", line 9, in ?
>       f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r') TypeError: an integer is required

I'm using python 2.4... because i've been challenged to not use anything newer, is there something about open() that I don't know about? Why does it want an integer?

anything after that line is untested. in short: why is it giving me the error and how do i fix it?

Comment: Your script has a bug in it. vals is a dictionary, which does not have an append method. You want to just assign with vals[t[0]]=t[1]

Comment: also, it's supposed to be "for line in f:" as opposed to val_f

Comment: yeah sev, i had gone through and changed my variable halfway through... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: so i had added another issue to my problem where i was getting a "file not found error"
the machine i'm on at work is set to hide extensions so the file was called in.txt.txt instead of just in.txt

Comment: cause == "machine ... is set to hide extensions"; effect = "the file was called in.txt.txt"???

Comment: yeah my comment was unclear, i was originally getting an error that the file in.txt was did not exist, but in my mind "that's impossible!"
so i started throwing things into my code. one of which was "from os import *"
that brought up a different error and i assumed i had fixed one problem to find another.
after this question was answered my code reverted back to the original error. So I edited my question to address the issue, upon finding that my machine was not showing extensions and that in.txt indeed did not exist i re-edited my question and left my previous comment in case it was read.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Because you did `from os import *`, you are (accidenally) using os.open, which indeed requires an integer flag instead of a textual "r" or "w".  Take out that line and you'll get past that error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching for the solution for so long. Finally could understand, where I overlook for so long. Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 15):

Don't do `import * from wherever` without a good reason (and there aren't many).

Your code is picking up the os.open() function instead of the built-in open() function. If you really want to use os.open(), do `import os` then call `os.open(....)`. Whichever open you want to call, read the documentation about what arguments it requires.

Answer (score 12):

Also of note is that starting with Python 2.6 the built-in function open() is now an alias for the io.open() function. It was even considered removing the built-in open() in Python 3 and requiring the usage of io.open, in order to avoid accidental namespace collisions resulting from things such as "from blah import *". In Python 2.6+ you can write (and can also consider this style to be good practice):

```
import io
filehandle = io.open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```

Answer (score 6):

Providing these parameters resolved my issue:

```
with open('tomorrow.txt', mode='w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict', buffering=1) as file:
    file.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm you could also keep your import and use

file = os.open( "foo.txt", mode )

and the mode could be :

```
os.O_RDONLY: open for reading only
os.O_WRONLY: open for writing only
os.O_RDWR : open for reading and writing
os.O_NONBLOCK: do not block on open
os.O_APPEND: append on each write
os.O_CREAT: create file if it does not exist
os.O_TRUNC: truncate size to 0
os.O_EXCL: error if create and file exists
os.O_SHLOCK: atomically obtain a shared lock
os.O_EXLOCK: atomically obtain an exclusive lock
os.O_DIRECT: eliminate or reduce cache effects
os.O_FSYNC : synchronous writes
os.O_NOFOLLOW: do not follow symlinks
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you should do:

```
open(sys.argv[2], "w", encoding="utf-8")
```

or

```
open(sys.argv[2], "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `from os import *` I also got the same error, remove that line and change it to `import os` and behind the os lib functions, add os.[function]