# Python: Creating and writing to a file error

Tags: python, io

I am having trouble creating and writing to a text file in Python. I am running Python 3.5.1 and have the following code to try and create and write to a file:

```
from os import *
custom_path = "MyDirectory/"
if not path.exists(custom_path)
    mkdir(custom_path)
text_path = custom_path + "MyTextFile.txt"
text_file = open(text_path, "w")
text_file.write("my text")
```

But I get a `TypeError` saying `an integer is required (got type str)` at the line `text_file = open(text_path, "w")`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as my code is just about identical to that of several tutorial sites showing how to create and write to files.

Also, does the above code create the text file if it doesn't exist, and if not how do I create it?

Comment: You can find the reply you need here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1046674/5179092

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't import everything from os module:

```
from os import path, mkdir
custom_path = "MyDirectory/"
if not path.exists(custom_path):
    mkdir(custom_path)
text_path = custom_path + "MyTextFile.txt"
text_file = open(text_path, 'w')
text_file.write("my text")
```

Because there also a "open" method in os module which will overwrite the native file "open" method.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you