# pickle error - integer required

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

```
with open('data', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dumps({'foo':111},f)
```

results in

```
an integer is required (got type _io.TextIOWrapper)
```

How can I fix this?

I am pretty sure [An integer is required? open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046656/an-integer-is-required-open) was not called beforehand.
Python version is `3.6.2`

Comment: [Second argument to `dumps` is _`protocol`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps). Did you mean `pickle.dumps({'foo':111},f)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) dumps `obj` into a string which it returns. In order to write into a file, you probably want to use [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) (without the s).

```py
with open('data', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump({'foo':111}, f)
```

Additionally you should also open the file in binary mode, because `pickle.dump` will write binary data.

Comment: I just edited the answer to mention the binary mode when opening the file.