# interger required to open file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, module

Okay so I need to do a file test for a program by creating/opening(if the file exists) and append some text to it to confirm that it works. Before I started adding in modules in the test went perfectly fine but once I finished putting in the modules and started working with the GUI with the `Tkinter` module now I get an error that an integer is required. There is a post about it but in there the person just messed up something with `readline()` which is not the case for me. I think it has to do with the `JSON` module or the fact that I added in `#!/usr/bin/env python` after the file test but I don't know.

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#shit to import
from json import *
from os import *
from sys import *
from numpy import *
from datetime import *
from tkinter import *

#testing
with open("test.txt","a") as file:
    file.read()
    file.write("The test has been completed \n")

#GUI
win = Tk()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to use the `file` as variable name. Consider switching to a different variable name such as `inFile`. Regarding your error, it has to do with `from os import *` line as it is mentioned in a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046656/an-integer-is-required-open).

Comment: `open` used to be nice. `os.open` is a different thing, that wants `flags` as the second argument (which have to be integer). `from os import *` replaced `open` with `os.open`. I highly suggest not doing `from stuff import *`, as you never know what could get overwritten.

Comment: @VasilisG. why? `file` isn't a builtin in Python 3 (they're not shadowing anything); the `from blah import *` is more probabilistic and worse style

Comment: @Chris_Rands you're absolutely right. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are doing `import *` stuff and builtin [open()](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.open) function replaced by [os.open()](https://kite.com/python/docs/os.open).

It's a bad idea to use `import *` stuff. Just import what you really need and you'll be happy ;)