# I keep getting this error in python3 "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so basically i have been working on a project that makes a login and signup system with python3 using tkinter
ive come to the point where i have to save the things inputed into a file with ***open()***
but it keeps giving me this error

```
    File "C:\Users\Kirill Rodionov\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\login.py", line 19, in storeData
    passwordFile = open("Passwords.txt", "a")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

this is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from os import *

nameFile = open("Names.txt", O_APPEND)
passwordFile = open("Passwords.txt", O_APPEND)

def SignUp():

    def storeData():

        name = signupNameEntry.get()
        password = signupPasswordEntry.get()
        rpassword = signupRPasswordEntry.get()

        print(name)
        print(password)
        print(rpassword)
        print(type(name))
        print(type(password))

        if password == rpassword:
            print("passwords match")
            nameFile = open("Names.txt", "a")
            passwordFile = open("Passwords.txt", "a")
            passwordFile.write(password)
            nameFile.write(name)
            passwordFile.close()
            nameFile.close()

        else:
            print("passwords don't match")


    signup = Toplevel()
    signup.title("Sign Up")

    Label(signup, text="Name", pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Label(signup, text="Password", pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
    Label(signup, text="Repeat\nPassword").grid(row=3, column=1)
    signupNameEntry = Entry(signup)
    signupNameEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    signupPasswordEntry = Entry(signup)
    signupPasswordEntry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    signupRPasswordEntry = Entry(signup)
    signupRPasswordEntry.grid(row=3, column=2)
    signupButton = Button(signup, text="Sign Up", command=storeData, pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=4, column=2)

    signup.mainloop()
```

the other part is the main loop i hope you get the code is the main loop i cant post the whole code because it says "your post is mostly code" 
btw im new to stackoverflow

Comment: It is not the whole code but it basically a function that gets called when a button is presed and it gets  the entries

Comment: Have you possibly redefined `open` somewhere?

Comment: Could you provide complete code so that i can run it and resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `from os import *`? In this case, it may be trying to use `os.open`. See [An integer is required? open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046656/an-integer-is-required-open).

Comment: You can still use `os`, but instead of using `from os import *`, specify explicitly which functions you want to import. For example, `from os import environ`. If there are multiple functions you want to use, separate them by a comma.